# I can't Open URL in iOS UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I can't open below URLS in UIWebview

http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3ccb/3/0/%2a/v%3B260459540%3B0-0%//3B1%3B42477956%3B2825-320/56%3B38531391/38549148/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3fhttp://www.google.com/

http://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/little-red-helicopter/id389086132?mt=8

Please help me to resolve these issue. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest showing us your code, otherwise it is impossible to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: advertisement_url= @"http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3ccb/3/0/%2a/v%3B260459540%3B0-0%3B1%3B42477956%3B2825-320/56%3B38531391/38549148/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3fhttp://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/little-red-helicopter/id389086132?mt=8";
    
    
    
    
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: advertisement_url]]]] ;

Answer (score 1):

iOS has a custom url scheme for iTunes Links, you can't open it in your webview because the OS will direct it into the iTunes/App Store.

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#App_Store